# How should multiple progress bars be handled in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a number of progress bars each tied to a div which are updated using 'setTimeouts'.

An example of how it runs is like this :

```
myDiv._timer = setTimeout(function () {
            func_name(data)
        }, 1);
```

**Edit**: As requested a working example of my one progress bar: http://jsfiddle.net/H4SCr/

The question however is, I have multiple div's with progression bars with their own data to use to calculate progression. Which means with say 5 on the go i have 5 different timeouts running.

I'm no expert in javascript, but surely theres a way to structure this to tie to just one time out for all progress bars, or is my current approach the best method ?

Note: i don't use jQuery. I prefer to go with just vanilla javascript to learn!

Comment: Why don't you give us a jsFiddle example for us to see it working?

Comment: Of my one progress bar ?

Comment: Yes, please that'd be really helpful :)

Comment: @HanletEscaño http://jsfiddle.net/MZc8X/3/

Comment: What do you mean 'structure this to tie to one time out'? Do you want them to load based on individual items finishing their work, or based on an estimate? The first one would rather some form of event handling, and the second a static animation timer.

Comment: Each progress bar is individual to items they are not linked to each other, but its really confusing to make a function where i can just create them and remove them when they are complete. Without being tied to a div with its own setTimeout calling itself over and over. @remyabel

Comment: You need some sort of state system probably that communicates with a manager. Essentially each entity is aware of when it's started, is in progress, and has stopped. The manager keeps track of all the entities and regulates them. This might sound overly complicated, but sometimes applying things like this to even simple things makes it easier to solve.

Comment: having 5 timeouts going, or even 20, is no big deal for any browser.

Comment: @VincentPiel doesn't mean its the best way to structure your JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check this out:**
http://jsfiddle.net/MZc8X/11/

I created an array of objects which contains the container id and its increment value.

```
// array to maintain progress bars
var pbArr = [{
    pid: 'bar1', // parent container id
    incr: 1 // increment value
}, {
    pid: 'bar2',
    incr: 2
}, {
    pid: 'bar3',
    incr: 3
}, {
    pid: 'bar4',
    incr: 4
}, {
    pid: 'bar5',
    incr: 5
}];
```

And, then call a function to create a progress bar...

```
var loopCnt = 1; // loop count to maintain width
var pb_timeout; // progress bar timeout function

// create progress bar function

var createPB = function () {

    var is_all_pb_complete = true; // flag to check whether all progress bar are completed executed

    for (var i = 0; i < pbArr.length; i++) {
        var childDiv = document.querySelector('#' + pbArr[i].pid + ' div'); // child div
        var newWidth = loopCnt * pbArr[i].incr; // new width
        if (newWidth <= 100) {
            is_all_pb_complete = false;
            childDiv.style.width = newWidth + '%';
        } else {
            childDiv.style.width = '100%';
        }
    }

    if (is_all_pb_complete) { // if true, then clear timeout
        clearTimeout(pb_timeout);
        return;
    }

    loopCnt++; // increment loop count

    // recall function
    pb_timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        createPB();
    }, 1000);
}

// call function to initiate progress bars
createPB();
```

Hope, it works for you.

Comment: Doesnt this limit it to just 5 progress bars ? If i added more  how could i make sure their id's are unique

Comment: You can add multiple progress bars with the help of id. If you are concerned about it, then you can add a single class to each progress bar and use to detect the progress bar.

Comment: so simple, but a great answer! When in doubt hashmap it out!