# How to access appended element in jQuery plugin and store it in a global variable?

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying slowly to move forward and create several jquery plugins which should be lightweight and do just what I need.

Now I want to make a super simple jQuery progress bar. The problem is that I can't access the element which is appended dynamically with jQuery `.append()`.

Here is the JSFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/LRHXf/6/

As you can see, the "children" `.smk_pb_child` should have a diferrent color and width, but for some unknown reason I can't make this to work.

How can I get this element in a variable and after this use it everywhere I need it?

Comment: There are several answers which helps you out. You can also try this: [create progress bar dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169270/how-should-multiple-progress-bars-be-handled-in-javascript/18169807#18169807). By changing its CSS, i think it might be good enough to use.

Comment: That was just an example, but what I'm trying to do is not only a progress bar, but much more plugins for diferrent use and the main problem was that I can't access dynamically created elements. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are initializing the `child` variable before you append the child element. You need to initialize the variable within the `appendChildren` method after you add the `smk_pb_child` div:

```
plugin.appendChildren = function () {
     plugin.append('<div class="smk_pb_child"></div>');
     child = plugin.children('.smk_pb_child');
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LRHXf/10/)**

Comment: Strange, I thought that I'm not allowed to declare a variable in a function and then use it in another. But probably because here we are talking about methods... Thanks it works like a charm.

Comment: You'll need to define the child variable in the plugin scope, then update the value within the appendChildren method.

Answer (score 2):

You set you var child before appending the element, you need to change the var inside you append function :

```
plugin.appendChildren = function() {
    plugin.append('<div class="smk_pb_child"></div>');
    child = plugin.children('.smk_pb_child');
}

var child;
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LRHXf/12/

Answer (score 0):

i see your jsfiddle demo and use this code

```
// Append children
        var appendhtml='<div class="smk_pb_child"></div>'; 
        plugin.appendChildren = function() {
                    plugin.append(appendhtml);
                }
```

or you can also use

```
var appendhtml=$("<div />").attr('class',"smk_pb_child");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending a string of html, try creating the html in jQuery and setting it to a variable, then appending the variable.

```
plugin.appendChildren = function() {
    plugin.myDiv = $('<div class="smk_pb_child"></div>');
    plugin.append(plugin.myDiv);
};
```